# Is the NESE community being stingy with upvotes?

Tags: discussion

So many of of our questions have 0 or 1 votes, it makes me think we are being way to stingy with our up-votes.

At the very least, every question with an answer should also have (at least) one upvote -- if the question deserves your time and attention to answer it, than surely you must have respected the question. The way to communicate that is with an upvote.

Similarly, if there are answers to questions that are sufficient, why not throw a few up votes to communicate to the author that their time was well spent.

In the end, the goal is to grow the community.  And the community will grow if new users feel rewarded by participating.

Comment: This has come up before. I have tried to do this, and there is the Electorate badge (Vote on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions), of which only six have been awarded. It looks like it has been awarded twice a year for the last three years.

Comment: My personal impression is that the community is stingy on the generation of questions worthy of upvotes. Most members who know enough to formulate high quality questions also know enough to not need to ask very many questions, it at all. Most questions that are posted seem to be from people relatively new to network engineering and many are off topic. We need people trying to intelligently learn how to read Cisco docs, we seem to get people trying to make their DSL faster so they can play XBox.

Comment: I think a lot of the "new" users are actually Sysadmins/Developers/Server peeps who work for a small enough org that no network engineer is on staff or available.  They get tossed into supporting systems that they didn't design and obviously don't have a great handle on.  But I think it's great - you have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

In short, yes, as a community our voting is quite low. There are some individuals that do vote more frequently than others.

We should vote more, but often I know I am so busy that I barely have time to moderate and don't think to cast the votes I should.

I don't know what the solution is, but feel free to suggest one.

Comment: It's going to have to be a trend that is set by example of the regulars. There are probably 10-20 folks that check this site (near) daily. That means every question and answer could theoretically have 10~ votes. Casting a vote is like money you can give away, that doesn't actually hold any value until it is given away -- aka, there is zero reason not to give it away every chance you get. So then, where we are left is how do we convince the regulars to vote often.